# Why does changing the width of div::before (on hover) work correctly at first, but fault thereafter?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a sort of "shooting star" animation on a button underline on hover. I've successfully achieved what I want and it's firing correctly on the first hover, but if you hover over it again the transition is glitchy and doesn't work as intended. The more you hover over it the less the width changes to the point where it no longer works.

I wondered if someone might be able to explain why this is happening?

Here is a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/r8g2a0em/6/)

```css
.btn {
      position: relative;
      font-size: 40px;
    }

    .btn::before {
      content: '';
      height: 1px;
      width: 100%;
      background-color: red;
      position: absolute;
      bottom: -1px;
      right: 0;
      -webkit-transition: all 0.5s linear;
      -moz-transition: all 0.5s linear;
      -ms-transition: all 0.5s linear;
      transition: all 0.5s linear;
    }

    .btn::after {
      content: '';
      height: 1px;
      width: 0;
      background-color: blue;
      position: absolute;
      bottom: -1px;
      left: 0;
      -webkit-transition: all 0.5s linear;
      -moz-transition: all 0.5s linear;
      -ms-transition: all 0.5s linear;
      transition: all 0.5s linear;
      -webkit-transition-delay: 0.5s;
      -moz-transition-delay: 0.5s;
      -ms-transition-delay: 0.5s;
      transition-delay: 0.5s;
    }

    .btn:hover::before {
      width: 0;
    }
    .btn:hover::after {
      width: 100%;
    }
```

```html
<a class="btn">Button</a>
```

Comment: `.btn:hover::before {
  width: 0 !important;
}
.btn:hover::after {
  width: 100% !important;
}`

Comment: Is it perhaps because the reverse animation is still ongoing when you return to the object? Undoing your animation _also_ takes `.5s`. Combine that with your `ease-in-out` timing function and it will appear to get out of sync. Try a couple of things: set your timing function to `linear` (our brains are better at understanding it in general) and change the color of your elements to be distinctive, so you have a clearer picture of what's actually happening.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @somethinghere. This has helped me to see the animation hasn't yet finished. Any idea how to get around that?

Comment: Is there a way to speed up the reverse animation?

Comment: Yes, set the `transition-duration` to a lower value on the regular element, and to the length you have now when you hover. It will speed up when the hover gets unapplied.

Answer (score 1):

With the help of @somethinghere, I was able to resolve this myself. For anyone who might need this in the future, the reverse animation was too slow so was incomplete before hovering over the element again. Adding a transition of 0 for the reverse animation solved the problem.

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/r8g2a0em/7/)

```css
.btn {
      position: relative;
      font-size: 40px;
    }

    .btn::before {
      content: '';
      height: 1px;
      width: 100%;
      background-color: red;
      position: absolute;
      bottom: -1px;
      right: 0;
      -webkit-transition: all 0s ease-in-out;
      -moz-transition: all 0s ease-in-out;
      -ms-transition: all 0s ease-in-out;
      transition: all 0s ease-in-out;
    }

    .btn::after {
      content: '';
      height: 1px;
      width: 0;
      background-color: red;
      position: absolute;
      bottom: -1px;
      left: 0;
      -webkit-transition: all 0s ease-in-out;
      -moz-transition: all 0s ease-in-out;
      -ms-transition: all 0s ease-in-out;
      transition: all 0s linear;
    }

    .btn:hover::before {
      width: 0;
      -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
      -moz-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
      -ms-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
      transition: all 0.4s linear;
    }
    .btn:hover::after {
      width: 100%;
      -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
      -moz-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
      -ms-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
      transition: all 0.4s linear;
      -webkit-transition-delay: 0.4s;
      -moz-transition-delay: 0.4s;
      -ms-transition-delay: 0.4s;
      transition-delay: 0.4s;
    }
```

```html
<a class="btn">Button</a>
```

Comment: you can remove the transition property on ::before and ::after elements right?

Comment: You transition delay should probably also be set to 0, as otherwise it will take .5s for the transition of 0s (instant) to occur. Also, keep them on your before and after, since you might want to just shorten it to something ridiculously small like `.1s` - too fast for most people to react to, but they can still see the elements elegantly reset itself.